# How to create an iterator for linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, iterator

```
public class Java_Practice {

private static class LinkedListTest {

    private String data;
    private LinkedListTest next;

    public LinkedListTest(String data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public LinkedListTest getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListTest next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LinkedListTest [data=" + data + ", next=" + next + "]";
    }

}

// Do a deep copy
private static LinkedListTest copyLlt(LinkedListTest original) {

    LinkedListTest copy = new LinkedListTest(original.getData() + " copied");

    LinkedListTest nextCopy = original.getNext();
    LinkedListTest current = copy;

    while (nextCopy != null) {

        LinkedListTest newCopy = new LinkedListTest(nextCopy.getData() + " copied");
        newCopy.setNext(nextCopy.getNext());

        current.setNext(newCopy);

        current = newCopy;
        nextCopy = newCopy.getNext();
    }

    return copy;
}
```

I have a code of linked list kinda like this. I want to create an iterator that has 3 private member: cur(current node), itnext(next node), and list(the whole list that we are iterating through). I was wondering how I can get the list value. And is there any way i can figure out the previous node of the current node? Sorry if this is a noob question. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66938/self-made-linked-list-iterator

Comment: To be able to find the previous item your `Node` class should have a previous link. This also permits faster lookups.  If your list has 150 items and the 145th is required, it is more efficient to count down from the end.

Comment: @sonnet I see, but this has a previous node. Mine is a singly linked list so it doesn't have a previous node

Answer (score 0):

The iterator doesn't need a next node private member, since it can get the next node from the current node. The question doesn't mention what methods you want to implement with the iterator.

> figure out the previous node of the current node?

With a single linked list, there's no simple way to traverse a list backwards. If methods don't involve traversing a list backwards, then an iterator could be a pointer (reference) to the previous node, which would require a dummy node to be used as the head node of a list so that every data node has a previous node.

With an iterator that points to the previous node, then insert and remove methods (as well as get and set data) could be implemented.

---

With a double linked list, a splice method (moves a node within a list or from one list to another) can be implemented, as well as traversing a list backwards.

Note that Java's native implementation of linked list iterators is something I consider to be a poor implementation, since it's derived from array oriented class, unlike C++ template library, which implements linked list as an independent doubly linked list container. With C++ std::list, there's no indexing, but instead std::next can be scan a list to emulate indexing, although it is slow. Since Java keeps an index in it's internal linked list iterator, any insert or removal of a node will invalidate all other iterators for that list, which is one of the reasons I consider it to be such a poor implementation. The other reason I consider Java list iterators to be poor is that Java iterators can't be copied (instead, you just get a duplicate reference to the same iterator object).